# How do I access the files on the other computers on my network from my Raspberry Pi 0W?

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

I have a raspberry pi 0 w with Raspbian Bullseye 4.1. Using version 3.0 of Rasbian, I could connect the Pi to my network and access files on other computers that were also connected to the network. When I upgraded to 4.1 and tried viewing files on another computer, it tried for a long time and then told me the connection timed out. How can view the files on other computers on my network.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/136889/edit) and tell us how you used to connect to other computers, such as SAMBA, sftp, ftp, NFS, or something else? We will need those settings too.

Comment: What on earth is "Raspbian Bullseye 4.1"?

Comment: If you are addressing other computers by hostname you may need to add the suffix .local to the hostname in bullseye

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question suggests that you may be confused with some of the fundamentals of operating your Raspberry Pi. I also have a RPi 0W, and it works fine - except for the fact that it is now quite slow.

We don't know how you upgraded, so it seems likely you may have made a mis-step during that process. Perhaps the best route to recovery is to do a *fresh* installation - i.e. install on a new SD card. The fresh install has the advantage that any files or data on your current SD card can be easily recovered & transferred to your new card once your system is up and running.

The best place for you to start may be in the "Official Documentation" - the [Getting Started - Installing the Operating System](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/getting-started.html#installing-the-operating-system) will walk you through all the steps. There are many alternatives to this procedure, but save those for another time.

You'll need to choose an **image** to install. Given the 0W has limited resources, I'd suggest you use one of the `Lite` distributions: either [`bullseye`](https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspios_lite_armhf/images/raspios_lite_armhf-2022-01-28/2022-01-28-raspios-bullseye-armhf-lite.zip) - or [`buster`](https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspios_oldstable_lite_armhf/images/raspios_oldstable_lite_armhf-2022-01-28/2022-01-28-raspios-buster-armhf-lite.zip).

Good luck, and feel free to post additional questions if you run into difficulties. There's a guide for posting questions here: [How do I ask a good question?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Please give that a read.